# Find out what user account was used to download a file

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

I'm on Windows 11.

I downloaded several PDF files last week from a web application and I want to know *exactly* how I got them (i.e.: all the possible metadata and information about the whole process).

My specific problem is that I had been logging in and out of the site, with a lot of different user accounts (for testing purposes). I would now like to determine what account I was using for each PDF file. The site is a very simple PHP web application. When you log in, it makes a POST request, the payload being `name=foo&password=bar`.

The PDF files details of Properties (`right click -> properties`) are scarce:

- Timestamp: 05/12/2023 09:50
- Type: Microsoft Edge PDF Document

`Get-ChildItem filename.pdf | Format-List *` doesn't add anything.

The Edge "Downloads" only shows the day. But in the database (`C:\Users\%USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\History`) there is a bit more of detail: I visited the web directory where the PDF is downloaded from 37 times in total.

Maybe a variation of this question is: "Are the POST request parameters stored somewhere in the client-side either by the browser or some system log?"

So I'm looking for ideas, suggestions, forensic tools, OS documentation to help me delve deeper into the investigation and trace as much as possible. I undestand that it's a server-side concern —as noted by @schroeder in the comments— but I'm just curious.

I first made this question in https://security.stackexchange.com/ (because of the security and forensic approach) but was automatically migrated here.

## UPDATE

Using DMDE, as @joep-van-steen suggested, give me this:

```
 LBA:27057216           vol.sec:27057216 Clus:3382152 sec:0  rec:0
 00000: 25 50 44 46 2D 31 2E 33  0A 33 20 30 20 6F 62 6A  %PDF-1.3.3 0 obj
 00010: 0A 3C 3C 2F 54 79 70 65  20 2F 50 61 67 65 0A 2F  .<</Type /Page./
 00020: 50 61 72 65 6E 74 20 31  20 30 20 52 0A 2F 52 65  Parent 1 0 R./Re
 00030: 73 6F 75 72 63 65 73 20  32 20 30 20 52 0A 2F 43  sources 2 0 R./C
 00040: 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 73 20  34 20 30 20 52 3E 3E 0A  ontents 4 0 R>>.
 00050: 65 6E 64 6F 62 6A 0A 34  20 30 20 6F 62 6A 0A 3C  endobj.4 0 obj.<
 00060: 3C 2F 46 69 6C 74 65 72  20 2F 46 6C 61 74 65 44  </Filter /FlateD
 00070: 65 63 6F 64 65 20 2F 4C  65 6E 67 74 68 20 37 31  ecode /Length 71
 00080: 39 3E 3E 0A 73 74 72 65  61 6D 0A 78 9C AD 96 5B  9>>.stream.xœ­–[
```

...etc... nothing here...

and:

```
     Entry Size:        96
     Attr. Size:        80
     Flags:             0
     Dir MFT Num:     > 144905     (68   )
     Creation Time:     2023-05-12 12:50:36.212
     Modification Time: 2023-05-12 12:50:36.880
     Change Time:       2023-05-13 20:16:19.056
     Access Time:       2023-05-18 01:40:25.940
     Allocated Size:    634880
     Size:              632787
     Attributes:        20
     Name Length:       7
     Name POSIX:        3
     Name:              doc.pdf
```

Comment: Did you try to go to the file in Edge's download page, right click, and choose "Copy Download Link?"

Comment: @schroeder yes, nothing there related to credentials

Comment: Some download links will include a path that includes usernames or user ID. Some files will include the username in the metadata. But in general, browsers don't need to know what account on the server side was being used. That's a server-side concern.

Comment: @schroeder I can't find anything. It's sort of a forensic stuff but there has to be some log somwhere with this data. I'm frustrated dude

Comment: Why "must" there be a log on the browser of what credentials were used or what account was accessed? As I said, that's a server-side thing.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. Browsers do not keep a transaction log like that. Only the URLs of pages you visit are stored in your browsing history. Neither request headers nor request bodies associated with these visits are kept around.

Unless the file itself is dynamically generated depending on who is downloading it, you will not be able to find out the account that was used.

You can however look at the surrounding activity for hints. If at some point the account name appears on the page title, that may have been recorded in your browser history. Or maybe you visited a profile page which has the account ID in the URL.

Comment: I'm trying with the surrounding activity. Once you log in the data appears in the source like this:`<input type=hidden name="name" value="test_name"><input type=hidden name="password" value="test_password">`. So it's on the client-side. What would you do?

Comment: Nothing. These contents are not available for you to check.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's helpful, but I'll leave that for you to determine.

Assuming the file was saved to an NTFS drive, downloaded files get an alternate data stream attached to them.

So if I look at a PDF I downloaded, we see:

[image]

If I 'dump' the entire data stream of the attribute:

```
0000: 5B 5A 6F 6E 65 54 72 61  6E 73 66 65 72 5D 0D 0A  [ZoneTransfer]..
     0010: 5A 6F 6E 65 49 64 3D 33  0D 0A 52 65 66 65 72 72  ZoneId=3..Referr
     0020: 65 72 55 72 6C 3D 68 74  74 70 73 3A 2F 2F 6E 65  erUrl=https://ne
     0030: 70 70 2E 6E 61 73 61 2E  67 6F 76 2F 66 69 6C 65  pp.nasa.gov/file
     0040: 73 2F 31 33 35 38 32 2F  30 37 2D 31 30 30 25 32  s/13582/07-100%2
     0050: 30 53 68 65 6C 64 6F 6E  5F 4A 50 4C 25 32 30 44  0Sheldon_JPL%20D
     0060: 69 73 74 72 75 62 25 32  30 54 65 73 74 69 6E 67  istrub%20Testing
     0070: 25 32 30 69 6E 25 32 30  46 6C 61 73 68 25 32 30  %20in%20Flash%20
     0080: 4D 65 6D 2E 70 64 66 0D  0A 48 6F 73 74 55 72 6C  Mem.pdf..HostUrl
     0090: 3D 68 74 74 70 73 3A 2F  2F 6E 65 70 70 2E 6E 61  =https://nepp.na
     00A0: 73 61 2E 67 6F 76 2F 66  69 6C 65 73 2F 31 33 35  sa.gov/files/135
     00B0: 38 32 2F 30 37 2D 31 30  30 25 32 30 53 68 65 6C  82/07-100%20Shel
     00C0: 64 6F 6E 5F 4A 50 4C 25  32 30 44 69 73 74 72 75  don_JPL%20Distru
     00D0: 62 25 32 30 54 65 73 74  69 6E 67 25 32 30 69 6E  b%20Testing%20in
     00E0: 25 32 30 46 6C 61 73 68  25 32 30 4D 65 6D 2E 70  %20Flash%20Mem.p
     00F0: 64 66 0D 0A 00 00 00 00                           df......
```

Some times the streams are non resident and contain more data, example:

```
LBA:18739016           vol.sec:18171720 Clus:2271465 sec:0  rec:0
 0000: 5B 5A 6F 6E 65 54 72 61  6E 73 66 65 72 5D 0D 0A  [ZoneTransfer]..
 0010: 5A 6F 6E 65 49 64 3D 33  0D 0A 52 65 66 65 72 72  ZoneId=3..Referr
 0020: 65 72 55 72 6C 3D 68 74  74 70 73 3A 2F 2F 72 65  erUrl=https://re
 0030: 61 64 65 72 2E 65 6C 73  65 76 69 65 72 2E 63 6F  ader.elsevier.co
 0040: 6D 2F 0D 0A 48 6F 73 74  55 72 6C 3D 68 74 74 70  m/..HostUrl=http
 0050: 73 3A 2F 2F 70 64 66 2E  73 63 69 65 6E 63 65 64  s://pdf.scienced
 0060: 69 72 65 63 74 61 73 73  65 74 73 2E 63 6F 6D 2F  irectassets.com/
 0070: 32 37 33 30 35 39 2F 31  2D 73 32 2E 30 2D 53 31  273059/1-s2.0-S1
 0080: 37 34 32 32 38 37 36 31  37 58 30 30 30 32 39 2F  742287617X00029/
 0090: 31 2D 73 32 2E 30 2D 53  31 37 34 32 32 38 37 36  1-s2.0-S17422876
 00a0: 31 37 33 30 30 34 31 35  2F 6D 61 69 6E 2E 70 64  17300415/main.pd
 00b0: 66 3F 58 2D 41 6D 7A 2D  53 65 63 75 72 69 74 79  f?X-Amz-Security
 00c0: 2D 54 6F 6B 65 6E 3D 49  51 6F 4A 62 33 4A 70 5A  -Token=IQoJb3JpZ
 00d0: 32 6C 75 58 32 56 6A 45  46 49 61 43 58 56 7A 4C  2luX2VjEFIaCXVzL
 00e0: 57 56 68 63 33 51 74 4D  53 4A 48 4D 45 55 43 49  WVhc3QtMSJHMEUCI
 00f0: 47 47 4D 75 59 76 44 79  6B 61 4B 4C 79 44 4F 6D  GGMuYvDykaKLyDOm
 0100: 50 68 6F 4B 4E 4C 34 6B  4B 61 65 31 30 53 42 25  PhoKNL4kKae10SB%
 0110: 32 42 6B 41 33 67 55 66  52 30 63 38 33 41 69 45  2BkA3gUfR0c83AiE
 0120: 41 25 32 42 61 34 6D 66  56 4D 37 57 48 45 33 6B  A%2Ba4mfVM7WHE3k
 0130: 55 39 4A 6C 30 37 35 25  32 46 25 32 42 71 57 70  U9Jl075%2F%2BqWp
 0140: 6E 43 6D 36 6D 25 32 46  35 52 47 25 32 46 4E 34  nCm6m%2F5RG%2FN4
 0150: 74 55 34 32 54 41 71 67  77 51 49 79 76 25 32 46  tU42TAqgwQIyv%2F
 0160: 25 32 46 25 32 46 25 32  46 25 32 46 25 32 46 25  %2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%
 0170: 32 46 25 32 46 25 32 46  25 32 46 41 52 41 45 47  2F%2F%2F%2FARAEG
 0180: 67 77 77 4E 54 6B 77 4D  44 4D 31 4E 44 59 34 4E  gwwNTkwMDM1NDY4N
 0190: 6A 55 69 44 42 44 72 76  51 38 41 33 52 77 6B 63  jUiDBDrvQ8A3Rwkc
 01a0: 25 32 46 4B 58 36 43 72  58 41 38 47 42 38 38 45  %2FKX6CrXA8GB88E
 01b0: 71 6F 41 6C 6D 30 6D 64  55 6B 50 65 73 25 32 42  qoAlm0mdUkPes%2B
 01c0: 76 52 6C 71 4E 56 54 64  69 35 53 65 35 59 4C 25  vRlqNVTdi5Se5YL%
 01d0: 32 46 6D 50 6F 50 41 52  78 51 34 57 32 6A 55 30  2FmPoPARxQ4W2jU0
 01e0: 77 62 68 59 62 48 54 38  48 6F 69 70 79 52 42 67  wbhYbHT8HoipyRBg
 01f0: 33 4F 25 32 46 35 64 64  35 6C 50 38 46 35 64 76  3O%2F5dd5lP8F5dv
 LBA:18739017           vol.sec:18171721 Clus:2271465 sec:1  rec:1
 0200: 4D 73 6A 65 44 4D 78 56  66 4C 4A 34 77 70 6D 4B  MsjeDMxVfLJ4wpmK
 0210: 77 33 63 52 42 41 50 45  63 66 36 75 71 62 63 72  w3cRBAPEcf6uqbcr
 0220: 25 32 46 79 57 64 53 4C  4D 63 6D 31 57 31 39 37  %2FyWdSLMcm1W197
 0230: 77 4A 37 71 71 55 50 76  6B 68 76 42 4D 71 64 37  wJ7qqUPvkhvBMqd7
 0240: 39 59 34 6E 4F 4A 74 66  46 73 70 78 38 70 5A 6D  9Y4nOJtfFspx8pZm
 0250: 58 33 77 41 4A 53 57 63  56 55 54 69 6D 6C 32 25  X3wAJSWcVUTiml2%
 0260: 32 46 4A 54 78 75 25 32  46 63 25 32 42 54 78 61  2FJTxu%2Fc%2BTxa
 0270: 45 49 62 69 45 6D 37 52  4E 6C 33 48 73 61 70 64  EIbiEm7RNl3Hsapd
 0280: 42 32 79 53 76 6A 66 4A  43 6B 6D 35 6D 6E 6B 6A  B2ySvjfJCkm5mnkj
 0290: 6C 4F 6F 43 49 4C 77 4C  4C 70 65 75 4C 35 47 41  lOoCILwLLpeuL5GA
 02a0: 67 71 58 77 39 4E 59 39  35 25 32 46 62 69 47 75  gqXw9NY95%2FbiGu
 02b0: 4B 56 56 5A 6C 66 42 34  4D 63 68 41 62 62 4E 42  KVVZlfB4MchAbbNB
 02c0: 6D 39 57 25 32 46 64 34  4F 73 32 50 47 47 67 76  m9W%2Fd4Os2PGGgv
 02d0: 64 25 32 46 34 71 77 41  32 56 4D 78 4D 79 56 47  d%2F4qwA2VMxMyVG
 02e0: 66 37 41 79 6C 30 47 39  57 31 4E 56 37 71 65 65  f7Ayl0G9W1NV7qee
 02f0: 6C 53 54 39 57 32 67 68  71 78 31 6D 72 51 38 64  lST9W2ghqx1mrQ8d
 0300: 6E 6F 59 56 37 57 78 25  32 42 70 69 4A 55 36 43  noYV7Wx%2BpiJU6C
 0310: 43 67 49 42 74 78 6B 6B  58 59 56 59 78 57 78 32  CgIBtxkkXYVYxWx2
 0320: 4B 71 46 68 25 32 42 4A  38 6C 33 4B 61 73 62 50  KqFh%2BJ8l3KasbP
 0330: 70 62 71 45 61 4B 39 6A  7A 65 25 32 42 4A 63 4D  pbqEaK9jze%2BJcM
 0340: 33 33 6F 69 63 66 61 6C  49 66 46 53 4A 6A 69 57  33oicfalIfFSJjiW
 0350: 71 66 56 7A 6C 53 4B 59  70 76 39 66 61 51 47 6F  qfVzlSKYpv9faQGo
 0360: 6C 59 42 54 71 77 63 64  4F 58 79 47 30 52 69 63  lYBTqwcdOXyG0Ric
 0370: 70 45 65 6C 35 4B 72 35  54 73 52 65 6C 4A 4D 57  pEel5Kr5TsRelJMW
 0380: 6A 71 53 63 66 46 64 65  49 72 55 63 72 78 47 64  jqScfFdeIrUcrxGd
 0390: 65 53 78 7A 32 7A 75 47  4E 49 58 4F 67 79 71 4E  eSxz2zuGNIXOgyqN
 03a0: 53 37 36 57 66 39 71 44  25 32 46 71 45 6B 44 65  S76Wf9qD%2FqEkDe
 03b0: 7A 43 33 6E 67 77 47 6B  30 46 35 68 36 79 75 30  zC3ngwGk0F5h6yu0
 03c0: 4F 39 39 32 57 70 6D 78  55 43 67 4B 6D 33 66 6E  O992WpmxUCgKm3fn
 03d0: 51 36 43 66 37 6B 67 63  34 7A 36 34 75 58 41 74  Q6Cf7kgc4z64uXAt
 03e0: 56 52 63 50 53 66 25 32  42 58 55 4E 48 4D 42 34  VRcPSf%2BXUNHMB4
 03f0: 45 25 32 42 4A 6D 68 36  32 56 47 78 56 34 6C 65  E%2BJmh62VGxV4le
 LBA:18739018           vol.sec:18171722 Clus:2271465 sec:2  rec:2
 0400: 45 43 74 63 61 48 61 31  74 42 47 78 31 4B 55 6A  ECtcaHa1tBGx1KUj
 0410: 43 50 64 70 45 6E 30 74  61 69 6E 46 6A 59 59 55  CPdpEn0tainFjYYU
 0420: 57 56 69 75 4B 65 6F 70  61 6F 58 57 42 44 45 50  WViuKeopaoXWBDEP
 0430: 4D 58 67 57 37 79 41 70  70 57 4B 59 30 55 7A 44  MXgW7yAppWKY0UzD
 0440: 59 33 64 53 52 42 6A 71  6C 41 57 76 79 35 25 32  Y3dSRBjqlAWvy5%2
 0450: 42 79 56 39 6A 67 56 78  6D 70 43 67 34 67 4E 56  ByV9jgVxmpCg4gNV
 0460: 47 4D 69 69 4E 68 4F 4B  6A 47 46 70 37 61 61 6A  GMiiNhOKjGFp7aaj
 0470: 39 54 45 46 4F 4E 57 76  62 73 6A 7A 34 65 69 25  9TEFONWvbsjz4ei%
 0480: 32 46 35 6D 38 52 59 72  61 37 25 32 46 6A 4F 65  2F5m8RYra7%2FjOe
 0490: 67 51 25 32 46 6B 6F 25  32 46 4E 42 50 6A 65 71  gQ%2Fko%2FNBPjeq
 04a0: 4F 38 5A 5A 37 69 4A 25  32 46 78 45 4B 78 25 32  O8ZZ7iJ%2FxEKx%2
 04b0: 46 4A 78 4B 49 53 41 65  33 32 76 36 6A 32 32 25  FJxKISAe32v6j22%
 04c0: 32 46 47 4A 71 77 42 4E  70 78 43 74 52 25 32 46  2FGJqwBNpxCtR%2F
 04d0: 49 4B 79 35 5A 63 70 75  52 4C 5A 6F 57 47 41 73  IKy5ZcpuRLZoWGAs
 04e0: 38 68 63 78 78 32 36 4E  35 4F 61 72 47 6B 34 58  8hcxx26N5OarGk4X
 04f0: 4A 25 32 46 66 35 68 4F  76 34 33 70 76 45 45 72  J%2Ff5hOv43pvEEr
 0500: 73 38 63 71 38 45 43 30  64 6B 34 4A 6F 48 4C 30  s8cq8EC0dk4JoHL0
 0510: 39 63 64 70 48 70 45 53  64 49 71 41 56 78 44 4C  9cdpHpESdIqAVxDL
 0520: 63 77 67 6E 59 47 55 7A  5A 46 53 64 36 34 68 68  cwgnYGUzZFSd64hh
 0530: 6E 6D 57 39 25 32 42 47  69 71 56 4B 51 25 33 44  nmW9%2BGiqVKQ%3D
 0540: 25 33 44 26 58 2D 41 6D  7A 2D 41 6C 67 6F 72 69  %3D&X-Amz-Algori
 0550: 74 68 6D 3D 41 57 53 34  2D 48 4D 41 43 2D 53 48  thm=AWS4-HMAC-SH
 0560: 41 32 35 36 26 58 2D 41  6D 7A 2D 44 61 74 65 3D  A256&X-Amz-Date=
 0570: 32 30 32 32 30 33 31 39  54 30 31 34 38 31 30 5A  20220319T014810Z
 0580: 26 58 2D 41 6D 7A 2D 53  69 67 6E 65 64 48 65 61  &X-Amz-SignedHea
 0590: 64 65 72 73 3D 68 6F 73  74 26 58 2D 41 6D 7A 2D  ders=host&X-Amz-
 05a0: 45 78 70 69 72 65 73 3D  33 30 30 26 58 2D 41 6D  Expires=300&X-Am
 05b0: 7A 2D 43 72 65 64 65 6E  74 69 61 6C 3D 41 53 49  z-Credential=ASI
 05c0: 41 51 33 50 48 43 56 54  59 59 47 53 44 59 51 48  AQ3PHCVTYYGSDYQH
 05d0: 52 25 32 46 32 30 32 32  30 33 31 39 25 32 46 75  R%2F20220319%2Fu
 05e0: 73 2D 65 61 73 74 2D 31  25 32 46 73 33 25 32 46  s-east-1%2Fs3%2F
 05f0: 61 77 73 34 5F 72 65 71  75 65 73 74 26 58 2D 41  aws4_request&X-A
 LBA:18739019           vol.sec:18171723 Clus:2271465 sec:3  rec:3
 0600: 6D 7A 2D 53 69 67 6E 61  74 75 72 65 3D 37 38 66  mz-Signature=78f
 0610: 37 62 31 65 30 61 64 34  63 36 32 61 37 61 30 37  7b1e0ad4c62a7a07
 0620: 65 37 36 39 34 61 66 61  39 64 32 65 63 34 38 34  e7694afa9d2ec484
 0630: 61 66 38 63 32 35 37 37  63 38 62 61 32 37 34 63  af8c2577c8ba274c
 0640: 37 37 37 61 65 62 61 61  30 61 61 62 66 26 68 61  777aebaa0aabf&ha
 0650: 73 68 3D 31 36 31 38 64  38 33 64 62 37 64 36 32  sh=1618d83db7d62
 0660: 64 63 32 62 65 63 62 33  31 35 33 64 65 39 31 35  dc2becb3153de915
 0670: 66 33 31 30 32 30 34 34  39 34 35 30 35 36 30 64  f31020449450560d
 0680: 65 64 37 31 66 62 30 61  63 37 31 66 30 34 37 61  ed71fb0ac71f047a
 0690: 62 62 33 26 68 6F 73 74  3D 36 38 30 34 32 63 39  bb3&host=68042c9
 06a0: 34 33 35 39 31 30 31 33  61 63 32 62 32 34 33 30  43591013ac2b2430
 06b0: 61 38 39 62 32 37 30 66  36 61 66 32 63 37 36 64  a89b270f6af2c76d
 06c0: 38 64 66 64 30 38 36 61  30 37 31 37 36 61 66 65  8dfd086a07176afe
 06d0: 37 63 37 36 63 32 63 36  31 26 70 69 69 3D 53 31  7c76c2c61&pii=S1
 06e0: 37 34 32 32 38 37 36 31  37 33 30 30 34 31 35 26  742287617300415&
 06f0: 74 69 64 3D 73 70 64 66  2D 37 37 61 62 61 64 30  tid=spdf-77abad0
 0700: 36 2D 36 39 39 32 2D 34  65 30 62 2D 61 33 31 30  6-6992-4e0b-a310
 0710: 2D 62 65 63 30 35 65 38  66 65 37 61 33 26 73 69  -bec05e8fe7a3&si
 0720: 64 3D 36 36 35 39 33 64  62 65 31 64 34 66 63 36  d=66593dbe1d4fc6
 0730: 34 34 37 39 35 62 39 32  31 39 33 64 33 32 65 32  44795b92193d32e2
 0740: 30 39 64 66 63 33 67 78  72 71 62 26 74 79 70 65  09dfc3gxrqb&type
 0750: 3D 63 6C 69 65 6E 74 26  64 6F 77 6E 6C 6F 61 64  =client&download
 0760: 3D 74 72 75 65 26 75 61  3D 35 33 30 32 30 34 35  =true&ua=5302045
 0770: 31 35 63 30 31 35 30 35  64 35 31 30 31 26 72 72  15c01505d5101&rr
 0780: 3D 36 65 65 32 38 62 35  33 36 63 37 65 34 31 35  =6ee28b536c7e415
 0790: 61 0D 0A 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  a...............
```

It reveals at least where it was downloaded from ..

Comment: Give me a moment while I learn how to use it. Thanks!

Comment: Look the update in the post please